# Implementing sign in with google (Google oauth) IOS

Tags: ios, oauth, gidsignin

I have implemented sign in with google i my project, now i don't want user should allow access every time he logs in the project. it should ask for first time only.

I have seen so many solution but don't have any idea how to implement. Please Any body  help me

Answer (score 0):

Keep a check at start. 
So on your checkViewController viewDidLoad

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if([defaults boolForKey:@"didLoginGoogle"]) //This returns false by default
{
    //Open the page/code for google login
}
else
{
    //Open your home page of the app without login
}
```

Also, once you are done with google login, do a -->

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool:true forKey:@"didLoginGoogle"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

And that it! Using defaults you store the state of your app and then navigate accordingly.